# display selected value as headertext in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

This is my select query in gridview:

```sql
SELECT
  matno,
  MAT_NAME,
  MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [CURRDATE],
  MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [previous_day],
  MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [Last_date]
FROM
  invorder 
WHERE
  (invorder.strno =54009) OR 
  ([invorder.deldate] IS NULL)
GROUP BY
  matno,
  MAT_NAME
```

When I select the dates in control these selected dates should display as column headers instead of:

```
[CURRDATE], [previous_day], [Last_date]
```

in the above query.

Comment: ya I placed text box for selecting date.no three dates(CURRDATE, previous_day and Last_date) are different dates selected from different controls (i.e two from text box control and one from calender control )

Comment: Is this a Winform, Webform application or else?